# Fastlane uses wrong cocoapod version

Tags: cocoapods, fastlane

When using fastlane and cocoapods to build our iOS app I noticed that fastlane does not use the version of cocoapods that I have installed using

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

When running

`pod --version`

it returns the latest version which is of this moment

> 1.3.1

However, when running a build lane in fastlane it uses cocoapods version 1.2.1 for some reason.

I use this in my Fastfile to clean and pod install

```
  cocoapods(
    clean: true,
    podfile: "Podfile"
  )
```

Is there a way I can tel fastlane to use a specific version of cocoapods? Or use the version I have installed manually?

Comment: where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 16):

It's recommended to [use a Gemfile](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile):

It is recommended that you use a `Gemfile` to define your dependency on *fastlane*. This will clearly define the used *fastlane* version, and its dependencies, and will also speed up using *fastlane*.

- Install [bundler](https://bundler.io/) using `sudo gem install bundler`
- Create a `./Gemfile` in the root directory of your project with the content:

> ```
> source "https://rubygems.org"
>
> gem 'fastlane'
> gem 'cocoapods'
> ```

- Run `[sudo] bundle update` and add both the `./Gemfile` and the `./Gemfile.lock` to version control
- Every time you run *fastlane*, use `bundle exec fastlane [lane]`
- On your CI, add `[sudo] bundle install` as your first build step
- To update *fastlane*, just run `[sudo] bundle update`

Comment: This is not working. I have Gemfile with cocoapods v 1.5.3 but fastlane uses 1.3.1 anyway

Comment: Yeah same issue here aswell. Installing a gem file did not help.

Comment: Any updates here? I'm having the same issue as @RafaelHovsepyan

Comment: Removing the `Gemfile.lock` and calling `bundle install` again fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

What helped me:

- I added a line to my `Pluginfile` (which lives next to the `Fastfile`):

```rb
gem 'cocoapods', '1.15.2'
```

where '1.15.2' - desired version of `cocoapods`

after changes my `Pluginfile` looks like next:

```rb
# Autogenerated by fastlane
#
# Ensure this file is checked in to source control!

gem 'cocoapods', '1.15.2'
gem 'fastlane-plugin-json'
gem 'fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution'
```